# Accent management with Restkit 0.20.3 and latin 9 encoding from the server side

Tags: ios, json, core-data, mapping, restkit-0.20

I try to map from a JSON content returned by my server with latin 9.

It works pretty well when there is no accent in my JSON, but as soon as RestKit try to manage some content with accent the mapping failed with this error:
Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'

I use RKManagedObjectRequestOperationfor the requesting, with an RKResponseDescriptor using RKEntityMapping and RKRelationshipMapping.

The mappy works, my only problems right now are the accents.

Hope some of you can help me,

Thanks.

Comment: Does the header say it's latin9 encoding?